# Canny edge detection not working on Gaussian blurred images

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to detect edges on this lane image. First blurred the image using Gaussian filter and applied Canny edge detection but it gives only blank image without detecting edges.

[image: input image]
[image]

I have done like this:

```
#imports
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

image= mpimg.imread("Screenshot from Lane Detection Test Video 01.mp4.png")
image = image[:,:,:3]
image_g = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

image_blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(image_g, (3, 3), 0)
threshold_low = 50
threshold_high = 100
image_blurred = image_blurred.astype(np.uint8)
image_canny = cv2.Canny(image_blurred, threshold_low, threshold_high)
plt.imshow(image_canny,cmap='gray')
```

Comment: Your code seems to work for me. Could you please share the original images?

Comment: Actually, this is a screenshot from a video. I read the screenshot. I don't understand what you mean by original images.

Comment: This is the screenshot from the following YouTube video: https://youtu.be/6q5_A5wOwDM

Comment: Thanks for sharing that, but it's not what I meant. If you want people here to be able to replicate your problem, you need to share the exact `image_g` that you pass to blur, not the results from `plt.imshow` that you get after your processing. I tested your code with random images, and it works for me, so it's probably an issue with the data type or something.

Comment: @Ash  Thanks for your patience.  I have updated my code  includes imports. , added input  image and output image. Can you please look into this issue. Thanks in advace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always examine your data. Simply running your script step by step and examining intermediate values shows what is going wrong: `mpimg.imread` reads the image as a floating-point array with values between 0 and 1. After blurring, you cast it to `uint8`, which sets almost all values to 0. Simply multiplying the image by 255 at some point before casting to `uint8` solves your issue.